# How to Turn My Code into Async Task?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a button that goes to another activity `FourthActivity` once clicked, but I keep receiving the following error on my Logcat: "Choreographer﹕ Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." I did a little research and discovered that using `AsyncTask` would get rid of it, but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Below is the code for `ThirdActivity.java`:

```
package elena.crosscountry.app;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.content.Intent;


    public class ThirdActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        Button staart;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

            staart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.staart);
            staart.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        private void staartClick(){
            startActivity(new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, FourthActivity.class));
        }

        public void onClick(View view){
            switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.staart:
                    staartClick();
                    break;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.third, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Below is the code for `activity_third.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ThirdActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/staart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i could not see any heavy work done on main thread is this the complete code?

Comment: It might be another thing that is causing error. not `Intent`. What is in `FourthActivity.class`?

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncTask` is a class that you can use to do lengthy background computing and later on, comunicating the result, such as:

- Downloading a file
- Calculating a long mathematical formula
- etc.

Starting an activity is not something you'd do with an `AsyncTask`. If you are getting that message while starting an activity, it's probably the new activity in its constructor, onCreate and onStart the one that is clogging the UI. Mind that when you start an activity, a lot of things happen:

- NEW ACTIVITY: `Constructor` -> `onCreate` -> `onStart` -> `onResume`
- OLD ACTIVITY: `OnPause` -> (maybe) `onStop` -> (maybe) `onDestroy`
- and the worse thing, the Garbage Collector often comes into play anytime between those steps, and when that happens, the UI is literally stopped for a (short) while. You can see it in the logcat with something like **"GC, freed xxxxKb, stopped for 100ms**"

All this happens sequentially and very fast. `Choreographer` is the main android loop, and it's telling you that it's been clogged and lost some frames somewhere in this process.

This can also depend on the phone/tablet hardware: Old hardware can easily get overwhelmed while stopping/starting an activity. If you have control of the new activity, just make sure it's not too heavy on initialization.

Comment: Thank you for your very informative reply! I'm quite new to Android Studio, so I'm not sure how to ensure that initialisation is not too heavy... What does that mean?

Comment: It means that your activity shouldn't do a lot of complicated stuff on the above methods, specially in the activity constructor, `onCreate` and `onStart`. These 3 are executed even before the activity is "painted", so for example if there you fill up a table with thousands of calculations, you'll experience a big delay until the activity is started and painted into the screen.